# Disable 'Next' button temporarily in Bootstrap Tour

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap Tour to build a rather restrictive tour in which the user can only proceed to the next step after spending 3 seconds on the current step.

In order to to do this, I gave the 'Next' button an id `nextBtn` in the tour template, and hope I can enable/disable it like this:

```
var tour = new Tour ({
    name: "my-tour",
    template: "...",
    onNext: function(tour) {
        $("#nextBtn").prop("disabled", true);
    }),
    onShow: function(tour) {
        window.setTimeout(next, 3000);
    });

function next() {
    $("#nextBtn").prop("disabled", false);
}
```

However, this is not working. What should be the right approach here?

Comment: typo `$("#nextBtn)` change it `$("#nextBtn")` you forgot to close quotes

Comment: @TusharGupta, sorry about the typo, but still not working.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Does the button not get disabled? Does it not get re-enabled? Does it not display a dancing hippopoatamus gif you are expecting it to?

Comment: @Becuzz, the button is not disabled

Answer (score 4):

There are some typos, but the main problem is that you have to use the correct selector to access the "Next" button, it is not `#nextBtn`, but it's a nesting of classes `$(".popover.tour-tour .popover-navigation .btn-group .btn[data-role=next]")`.

In the `onShow` and `onNext` event the popover is not accessibile because boostrap destroy and recreate it, the correct event is `onShown`:

> Function to execute right after each step is shown.

Code:

```
var timer;
var tour = new Tour({
    onShown: function (tour) {
        $(".popover.tour-tour .popover-navigation .btn-group .btn[data-role=next]").prop("disabled", true);
        timer=window.setTimeout(next, 3000);
    }
})

function next() {    
    $(".popover.tour-tour .popover-navigation .btn-group .btn[data-role=next]").prop("disabled", false);
    window.clearTimeout(timer);
}

tour.addStep({
    element: "#one",
    title: "Step 1",
    content: "Content for step 1"
})

tour.addStep({
    element: "#two",
    title: "Step 2",
    content: "Content for step 2"
})

tour.addStep({
    element: "#three",
    title: "Step 3",
    content: "Content for step 3"
})

tour.start()
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/3YY7Y/

Comment: The issue is not the id selection, as I explicitly set the id of the 'next' button in the template. Inspecting the html generated at each step clearly shows the 'next' button has the desired id. The issue is that, for some reason, there is a delay between the `onShown` callback is called and when the `next` button is ready to be selected. So If I do something like: `window.setTimeout(disableNext, 200);` inside `onShown` (where inside `disableNext`, we do `$("#btn_id").prop("disabled", true);`), it will disable the button (after 0.2 sec delay). I'm not sure if this is a bug in bootstrap-tour.

Comment: You don't post the templare so I used the default; for the event you must use onShown as detailed in the answer.